# I'm mixed up in my Definitions for a closed and open Set in Topology

Tags: general-topology

I tried to understand topology recently and I'm confused on what is considered open and closed in Topological sets/spaces.

Say you have a function where there exists some $$(\alpha-\delta,\alpha+\delta)\text{ of function C}$$

$$C(\alpha) = (0,5] \cup \{6,7,8,9\} \cup [10,20)$$

it's my understanding that natural number "steps" would be closed (or vice-versa) and that Real Numbers

$$(0,5] \text{ and } [10,20)$$

would be open (or vice-versa) if $$\delta\gt 0$$

I thought that being open or closed on an interval had to be such that, if it's an infinite "step" it would be closed and if it's zero, or rather a finite "step" from the next number, then it would be open? I know it has something to do with the fact of using

```
"[" or "(" notation
```

**Which is which, and is this true?** Please excuse, but is there a "**kindergarden**" way to understand and differentiate these?

So say you had an interval $$(5\to10\} \cup [10\to20]$$ compared with this one Say you had an interval $$(5\to10\} \cup \{10\to20]$$

would that be closed from 10} to [10 or would the second one be closed?
Let me know how I can improve this question please, Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean above. What does $\epsilon-\delta$ of interval...' mean? The terminology for intervals, points, etc. of the real line is fairly well established, it would be better if you stuck to that...

Comment: Being open (in this case) means that for any point in the set, there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that all points less than $\epsilon$ away are also in the set.

Comment: Whether "the real numbers from 0->5" are open or closed depends entirely on whether 0 and 5 are included in that set.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't know why, but thats how my neurons stored the delta notation, thankfully I went to the book for my edits

Comment: @MartianInvader I really do understand what you say, but I easily confuse the two, is there a "simple-stupid" way to differentiate and memorize this distinction?

Comment: Just practice. ${}{}{}$

Comment: I'm assuming that, as on a surface, a break in the function would represent a tear, but what does a set of natural numbers have to do with describing a particular type of surface? Please excuse me if I didn't see that this whole time. I feel as though I'm caught up in the formalism and not seeing the shape.  @MartianInvader does it essentially only have to do with "5" being included in the set?

Comment: I think that I forgot something, isn't there something about integer numberings are necessarily closed? That may have resolved my whole issue of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia - Explanation of Open Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set) really helped out. So, the intuitive understanding of a closed set is a set with a border, by contrast and exclusion, an open set is a set without a border.

$(n_1, n_2)\ \ | \ n_1,n_2 \in R$  is an open set, and

$[n_1, n_2]\ \ | \ n_1,n_2 \in R$ is a closed set.

$(n_1, n_2]\ \ | \ n_1,n_2 \in R$ is left half open

$[n_1, n_2)\ \ | \ n_1,n_2 \in R$ is right half open